# Very large table size but with few rows

Tags: postgresql

I have this table with only 1M rows but size is 49GB
[image]

I have run **pg_column_size** on each column and I got this

[image]

Uniq index size:

- index_items_on_profile_id_and_code_and_sku: 2.64GB
- unique_null_sku_code: 6.36 MB

How can I understand the reason of this size so large?

PG STAT USER TABLE

```
select * from pg_stat_user_tables;
```

[image]

SCHEMA DB

```
create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "profile_id", null: false
    t.bigint "category_id"
    t.string "title"
    t.string "image"
    t.string "code"
    t.string "sku"
    t.string "parent_code"
    t.datetime "created_at", default: -> { "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" }, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", default: -> { "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" }, null: false
    t.string "brand"
    t.decimal "price"
    t.string "crawling_status"
    t.decimal "spend", default: "0.0"
    t.decimal "sales", default: "0.0"
    t.string "manufacturer"
    t.string "status", default: "", null: false
    t.string "images", array: true
    t.string "eligibility_status"
    t.json "eligibility_list"
    t.boolean "active", default: true, null: false
    t.index "profile_id, code, ((sku IS NULL))", name: "unique_null_sku_code", unique: true, where: "(sku IS NULL)"
    t.index ["profile_id", "code", "sku"], name: "index_items_on_profile_id_and_code_and_sku", unique: true
  end
```

PG COLUMN SIZE QUERY

```
select
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('items')) as pg_relation_size,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('items')) as pg_total_relation_size,
    pg_size_pretty (pg_indexes_size('items')) as pg_indexes_size,
    pg_size_pretty (pg_tablespace_size('items')) as pg_tablespace_size
FROM (
    select
        
        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(profile_id))) as profile_id,
        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(category_id))) as category_id,
        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(title))) as title,
        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(image))) as image,
        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(code))) as code,
        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(sku))) as sku,
        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(parent_code))) as parent_code,
        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(created_at))) as created_at,
        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(updated_at))) as updated_at,
        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(brand))) as brand,
        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(price))) as price,
        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(crawling_status))) as crawling_status,

        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(spend))) as spend,
        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(sales))) as sales,
        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(manufacturer))) as manufacturer,
        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(status))) as status,



        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(images))) as images,
        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(eligibility_status))) as eligibility_status,
        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(eligibility_list))) as eligibility_list,
        pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(active))) as active

    from items
) i
```

**POSTGRES config**
https://pastebin.com/9Z2nwBLy

Comment: Could you show us the result from this query: select * from pg_stat_user_tables;

Comment: Is it possible that you have really large values in the JSON column? Or in any of the other "string" columns (assuming those are `text` columns in the database - I don't know what that syntax is supposed to be, it's not SQL)

Comment: "*I have run pg_column_size " - please show us that query (as formatted text, no screen shots please)

Comment: Added. Sorry for screenshot I don't know how to better paste table results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With over 200 million dead tuples, it might be the right time to do a [VACUUM FULL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-vacuum.html) on this table. It will lock the table for a while, rewriting the table. [REINDEX](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reindex.html) will rewrite the indexes as well.

You could also install and use [pg_repack](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack)

Comment: OP should fix the problem too. I'd prefer pg_squeeze over pg_repack.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: What are the benefits from pg_squeeze? Besides being created by Cybertec ;-)

Comment: Great! It now dropped to 472 MB!! Thank you. Do you know why is it run automatically? I have added postgres config at the end

Comment: @FrankHeikens The main advantages are 1) it runs completely inside the database 2) it has a scheduler that automatically reorganizes a table when certain criteria are fulfilled.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Thanks! I'll give it try and if I need help, I'll let you know

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your `pg_stat_user_tables` output, your table is bloated out of shape with dead tuples (over 200 million dead tuples for 1 million live tuples).

There is something that blocks autovacuum progress: either you disabled autovacuum, or you have very long running transactions (perhaps stale prepared transactions), or you have a stale replication slot.

Fix whatever problem is blocking `VACUUM`, then reorganize the table to remove the bloat with `VACUUM (FULL)`.

Comment: Great! It now dropped to 472 MB!! Thank you. Do you know why is it run automatically? I have added postgres config at the end

Comment: The config doesn't give a clue. I'd activate `log_autovacuum_min_duration`, perhaps something is logged. Other than that, I gave some pointers in my answer.